# Poisson Conditional Probability - Abandoned Cars

Tags: discrete-mathematics, poisson-distribution, conditional-probability

The question in my assignment is,

Suppose that N, the number of cars abandoned weekly on a certain highway, is a Poisson
random variable with parameter 2.2, i.e.

P(N = n) = 
(n = 0, 1, 2, . . .) $\frac{e^-2.2((2.2)^n)}{n!}$ (So poisson distribution!) exp

Find the Probability that there is:

(a) no abandoned cars in the next week [5]
(b) Find the probability that at least 3 abandoned cars in the next week. given that 1
abandoned cars in the next week.

I feel like (b) is ambiguous but my solution is,

P(N>=3|N>=1)= P(N>=3)/P(N>=1)

= (1-P(N<3))/(1-P(N>=1))

= 0.4243

If anyone has any thoughts if I went wrong it's be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Hi. Welcome. Looks fine to me if you replace $1-{\rm P}(\rm N\ge1)$ in next to last line by $1-{\rm P}(\rm N<1)$. And I agree with you that the question is ambiguous. Should be "given that AT LEAST 1 abandoned car". BTW, please use LaTeX formatting for your messages, it will be much more easy to read you.

Comment: Apologies that is what I had just typed wrong, thanks for the feedback, I'm new to stackexchange so the feedback is appreciated!

Comment: As Nicolas said in the comments the denominator should be $1-P(N<1)$ which is precisely $1-P(N=0)$, anyway numerically speaking I obtained a different result. My calculations went as follows:  

$$1-P(N<3)=1-e^{-2.2}(1+2.2+\frac{2.2^2}{2!}+\frac{2.2^3}{3!})=0.1806$$

on the other hand the denominator is as said: $$1-P(N=0)=1-e^{-2.2}=0.889$$

Finally $\frac{0.1806}{0.889}=0.203$

Comment: Why do you include P(N=3) for P(N<3)?